# A word to describe an assistant who knows when to ask me for help on cases he is not familiar with?

Tags: single-word-requests, academia

I have an assistant who helps me deal with some daily works.

Currently, he deals with everything on his own. Apparently, there are cases he is not familiar with, but he never reports them to me. So I have to check all his results, which costs me a lot of time.

I hope that for cases he is familiar with, he could do it himself; but for the cases he is unfamiliar with, he should ask me for help, or mark those cases for me. So that I only need to check the cases he asked for help.

Finally, I want to say, this is actually a word choice problem in academic writing. We are designing a virtual assistant, and want a word to distinguish it from previous `know-all` assistants.

So what is the best word for the following blanks?

- You should be __ on this work.
- I want a __ assistant for this work.
- We design a virtual assistant that is __ comparing with existing ones.

Answer (score 2):

I characterise the assistant you need as ***communicative***. Being communicative is one of the qualities we most value in other people and we all agree that many mess ups occur because of lack of communication and one instance of that is what you are describing.

[OxfordL](https://www.google.com/search?q=communicative%20meaning&sxsrf=AOaemvLN-AlC4pmMIGXjOeXaQEGMGYe9vw%3A1630092524322&source=hp&ei=7DwpYbffEMG4adu8j9AH&iflsig=ALs-wAMAAAAAYSlK_BrerMQySBte8K_UwGvrPc8ytQ_d&oq=communicative%20m&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAEYADIPCAAQgAQQhwIQFBBGEPkBMgQIABAKMgUILhCABDIFCAAQgAQyBQgAEIAEMgQIABAKMgQIABAKMgQIABAKMgQIABAKMgQIABAKOgcIIxDqAhAnOgkIIxAnEEYQ-QE6BAgjECc6BQgAEJECOggILhCxAxCDAToOCC4QgAQQsQMQxwEQowI6CAgAELEDEIMBOgoILhDHARCjAhBDOgoIABCxAxCDARBDOggIABCABBCxAzoLCAAQgAQQsQMQgwE6BwgAELEDEEM6BAgAEEM6CAguEIAEELEDOggIABCABBDJAzoFCAAQkgM6DQgAEIAEEIcCELEDEBQ6BwguELEDEEM6DgguEIAEELEDEMcBEK8BOgUIABCxAzoLCAAQgAQQsQMQyQM6BwgAEIAEEApQ4BJY9C9gloQBaAJwAHgBgAHdPYgBwJsBkgERMC43LjAuNC4wLjMuMS45LTKYAQCgAQGwAQo&sclient=gws-wiz) defines at as meaning:

> willing, eager, or able to talk or impart information.

[Yourdictionary](https://www.yourdictionary.com/communicative) adds:

> Giving information readily; forthcoming; Inclined to communicate readily; talkative.

Here is what a site writes about [*communication skills between boss and assistant*](https://csuiteassistants.com/blog/better-ways-to-communicate-with-your-executive-assistant/):

> If there is a breakdown in communication between you and your assistant, or if effective communication skills and practices were never established in the first place, everything can all fall apart. You may find yourself completing tasks you would normally delegate because you’re worried they won’t be done correctly...

And [business2community](https://www.business2community.com/communications/good-communication-is-essential-when-working-with-a-virtual-assistant-02258141) asserts that:

> Good communication is essential in any relationship but when your team is virtual it is crucial.

Answer (score 0):

I gather the word should describe someone who takes responsibility/initiative in some cases, but not others, according to instructions, knowledge, or experience.

**judicious** (adj.)

> Of a person, or a person's character, faculties, etc.: having or
> exercising sound judgement; (in later use) esp.  (a) wise in
> intellectual matters; discerning, discriminating;  (b) sensible in
> practical matters; capable in adapting means to ends; careful,
> prudent.
>
> Of action, thought, writing, etc.: proceeding from or showing sound
> judgement; done with or marked by discretion, wisdom, or good sense.
> OED

---

> The natural quick understanding of his wife had been strengthened and
> expanded by the education which he had given her the means of attaining,
> and she became a most active and **judicious assistant** to him in all his
> most intricate concerns. [*The Private Journal of the Marquess of
> Hastings*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Private_Journal_of_the_Marquess_of_H/IxcdAAAAMAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=judicious%20assistant&pg=PA174&printsec=frontcover).

> But if the same narrator narrates and extraordinary incident that runs
> counter to general experience and connot be reconciled to the
> attendant circumstances, it should then require a stronger evidence
> and the reporter has to be uncommonly **judicious**, discerning, and
> scrupulous, far above average. [M. Moaddel, K. Talatoff; *Modernist
> and Fundamentalist Debates in Islam*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Modernist_and_Fundamentalist_Debates_in/YOYYDAAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=judicious%20discerning&pg=PA64&printsec=frontcover)

Answer (score 0):

Unlike your know-it-all assistant, your new assistant has been trained to distinguish between familiar and unfamiliar tasks. It knows what it doesn’t know.

In machine learning terms, it performs [binary classification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_classification) — “the task of classifying the elements of a set into two groups on the basis of a classification rule” — in order to flag the tasks that are unfamiliar to it.

The verb *distinguish* has a couple of pertinent meanings here:

> **distinguish**, *v.*
> **2.** To divide into classes or species; to class, classify.
> **4. a.** To recognize as distinct or different; to separate mentally (things, or one thing *from* another); to perceive or note the
> difference between (things); to draw a distinction between.
> <sub>Source: [Oxford English Dictionary](https://oed.com) (login
> required)</sub>

With the act of distinguishing, your assistant can not only understand the difference between the familiar and unfamiliar but also act on that understanding (by classifying).

So:

> *Unlike the know-it-all assistant, which performs familiar and unfamiliar tasks with equal confidence, our assistant can distinguish
> tasks, flagging unfamiliar ones for your review. It’s a
> task-distinguishing assistant.*

You could also try out some synonyms — perhaps *discerning* or *discriminating* to emphasize the ability to recognize differences, or *differentiating* or *sorting* to emphasize the act of classifying.